# Sending ethers to named function with parameters fails

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js

I am trying to send ethers to a named function with parameters, But for some reason the transaction fails, according to my understanding this has something to do with the type of parameters, because it works when the parameter type is "address" but fails with "string", "bytes32", "uint256". solidity version: pragma solidity ^ 0.4.15;
Please find the code below:

This fails:

```
struct transact{
    address to;
    address from;
    uint amt;
    uint256 timeStamp ;
}

mapping(string => transact) transactions;


function addTransaction(string _transactionId, uint256 _timestamp, address _to) payable{

    transactions[_transactionId].from = msg.sender;
    transactions[_transactionId].amt = msg.value;
    transactions[_transactionId].to = _to;
    transactions[_transactionId].timeStamp = _timestamp;

}

function getTransactionDetails(string _transactionId) constant returns(address, address, uint, uint256){

    return (transactions[_transactionId].from, transactions[_transactionId].to, 
    transactions[_transactionId].amt, transactions[_transactionId].timeStamp);

}
```

How i call is:

```
constractInstance.addTransaction("123", 1234, "0x59826af1c1b5beed865a835ea42493d1877fca15",{ from: web3.eth.coinbase, value:web3.toWei(1000, "ether")});
```

For testing purpose i tried this

This Works

```
struct transacttest{
    address to;
    address from;
    uint amt;
}

mapping(address => transacttest) transactionstest;

function addTransactiontest(address _to) payable{

    transactionstest[_to].from = msg.sender;
    transactionstest[_to].amt = msg.value;
    transactionstest[_to].to = _to;

}

function getTransactionDetailstest(address _to) constant returns(address, address, uint){

    return (transactionstest[_to].from, transactionstest[_to].to, 
    transactionstest[_to].amt);

}
```

Comment: Is the `constractInstance.addTransaction()` (sic) call the one that is failing for you? What output are you getting on the failure? That same call is succeeding in remix for me.

Comment: @carver yes this complete thing works perfectly in remix. But acts weird when i work on private blockcahin. i have not checked the debug logs on ethereum. I just want to know is there any thing special that we need to take care of while calling named payable function with params, Like making sure about the params type?

Comment: The type of the parameters must match the function definition, that's all. Can you tell us more about what goes wrong on the private chain? "Acts weird" isn't much to go on.

Comment: Likely the culprit is the string parameter, they are expensive to store and retrieve, you have to increase the amount of gas if the default is not enough try `.addTransaction(..., { ...., gas: 2000000 })`.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks bro, Gas was the problem, wasted so much time on this. You saved me